# Facebook authentication via android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am new to android. I am developing an application which requires facebook login to proceed. So for this I have followed this tutorial - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

**EDIT:** Using UILifecycleHelper, same thing happen, once user authenticates the application application is closed.

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.w("Vinit", "Session started");
              // make request to the /me API
              Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    t.setText("User: " + user.getFirstName());

                  }
                }
              }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    };

    private FacebookDialog.Callback dialogCallback = new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        if(new LoginChecker(this).isRegistered()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);            
            LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton1);
            thisActivity = this;
            loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                              
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(thisActivity, callback);
                }
            });

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Log.w("Vinit", "On Activity Result function");
          uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, dialogCallback);
    }
```

Comment: Is it calling `onActivityResult`?

Comment: no its not calling onActivityResult

Comment: Is your `session` already created ? check
`Session session = Session.getActiveSession(); 
  if(session==null){                      
      // try to restore from cache
      session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(mActivity);
  }`

Comment: if session from cache comes null or not opened then call `openActiveSession`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use UiLifecycleHelper 
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/UiLifecycleHelper
   to be sure that your activity/fragment handle processing from facebook component in proper way.
2. Check Facebook Session object.
   Does app call instructions inside session.IsOpened()? Try debug your code to see state of the Facebook Session.

Comment: Hi Mate, It never goes into Session.isOpened() code. I have placed a breakpoint but never goes there. Also I have placed a log.d() there but nothing coming on logcat as well.

Comment: Did you try with UiLifecycleHelper? Do you have correct AndroidManifest? Read carefully https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate

Comment: Hi Mate, I have used UILifeCycleHelper but same result, please see updated code, I will refer to the other link you posted. thanks